# Convert a JSON into a list of key value pair

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a string which has multiple JSON in it of the format:

```
ID,{JSON},
ID,{JSON},
ID,{JSON}
```

I want to convert this into a list of key-value pairs in which each key-value pair is of the format mentioned below:

```
{
 Key: "ID",
 Value: {JSON}
}
```

Let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel first I tried to parse the string into a JSON using JToken.Parse but didn't know how to proceed from there

Comment: Try parsing a `JObject` instead of a `JToken`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your strings into a serializable class with two properties key and value and serialize it.